# mingw5.4 : cannot open output file /home/user1/test.o: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I am building my test.c using `mingw5.4` using command:

```
/software/mingw5.4/bin//x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.cxx -o /home/user1/test.o
```

But I am getting following error:

```
    c:/cygwin64_new/home/admin/software/mingw5.4/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
cannot open output file /home/user1/test.o: No such file or directory
```

If I use version `mingw4.8.3` the same file is compiling fine.

```
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.cxx -o /home/user1/test.o
```

If anybody know reason of error in case of version `mingw5.4` please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

LOL. I've done that. There is a command called `test` on *nix systems. Some shells have it built in (for speed). Try running `./test` or `text.exe` or call the executable something else.